# What exactly does Adobe mean by VertexShader have a limit of 8 inputs?

Tags: flash, assembly, vertex-shader, stage3d

Does it mean only a total of **8 float** values can be passed per vertices's set of data?

Does this mean you can only have one of the following?

- **2** inputs of **FLOAT_4**.
- **4** inputs of **FLOAT_2**.
- **8** inputs of **FLOAT_1**.
- Any mixture that will add up to a total of **8 float** values?

Is this the case? Because if it is, it's really misleading in their documentation to say 8 inputs can be used.

Maybe I'm having trouble because I haven't formatted my data correctly, but I'm trying to use **9 floats** per *vertices*, as in:

- va0 would be a **FLOAT_4**, offset set at **0**.
- va1 would be a **FLOAT_4**, offset set at **4**.
- va2 would be a **FLOAT_1**, offset set at **8**.

But nothing appears on the screen with this experiment. Am I exceeding the VertexShader inputs limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem.

If you define more values in your vertex-data (per vertices), such as making a modification from this format:

```
position: x  va0.x
          y  va0.y
          z  va0.z
          w  va0.w
color:    r  va1.r
          g  va1.g
          b  va1.b
          a  va1.a
```

to something like this:

```
position: x  va0.x
          y  va0.y
          z  va0.z
          w  va0.w
color:    r  va1.r
          g  va1.g
          b  va1.b
          a  va1.a
uv:       u  va2.x
          v  va2.y
```

Great... you added a new register to the mix. But what you have to do is:

- Make sure to pass in the right values in:

  `context3D.createVertexBuffer(numOfVertices, vertexDataLength);` and...

  `uploadFromVector(_vertexData, 0, numOfVertices);`
- Make sure you set the right offsets in your calls to:

  `context3D.setVertexBufferAt(2, vertexBuffer, 8, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_4);`
- Last but certainly not least (exactly what I was missing)... make USE of that register in your shader!

If you added a new vertex-attribute but you don't use it in your AGAL code... it won't render!

Hopefully this saves others some time wondering where they went wrong with their shaders!

**Note: I know, common sense - if you create something, why wouldn't you use it anyways? I was testing if the previous shader still worked with the extra data. It does, as long I don't assign my new vertex-attribute (va2) in the mix. So if you're testing, make sure to only use `setVertexBufferAt(...)` with the input registers you'll actually use.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limit is not about the size of vertices, but about the number of vertex attributes in your GLSL shader.

I'm not too familiar with Stage3D, but this is more an OpenGL question. In pure OpenGL, you have to enable vertex attributes with the function `glEnableVertexAttribArray(int)`. What this limitation means is that the only valid numbers for this method are 0 through 7.

In a way that is easier to check against your own code, this isn't allowed in a vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 in_one;
attribute vec4 in_two;
attribute vec3 in_three;
attribute vec2 in_four;
attribute vec4 in_five;
attribute vec3 in_six;
attribute vec4 in_seven;
attribute vec2 in_eight;
attribute vec4 in_nine;
...
void main()
{
    ...
}
```

Note: size of attributes (vec2-4) don't matter, the fact that there are 9 attributes would be passing the limit.

Comment: Okay, I think your explanation is applicable to AGAL (the Stage3D shader language) as well. Maybe I've just messed up something in my custom vertex data / shader, or set an incorrect offset for each attributes. I'll check again - Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible I need to pass my vertex-data in more than one VertexBuffer? I'm trying to pass everything as one big long Vector (or Array). I have 4 vertices of 9 pieces of float values each, so a total of 36 numbers in my vertex-data. Would it be better if I pass each specific sets of data in separate vertex-buffers? like positions (XYZ) in one, colors (RGBA) in another, UV in yet another?

Comment: That would be a nice way of isolating the issue, but that reminds me of another potential error - your stride values. I know I had this issue a lot, offset and stride are measured in **bits** and not bytes. And the stride is the number of bits between the first bits of each vertex attribute. So in your case, positions would have offset 0, stride 36, colors offset 16, stride 36, and UV would be offset 32, stride 36.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look more into 'stride values'. If it's the issue, I'm afraid there's no control on that from the ActionScript side - might be a good issue to report to Adobe.

Comment: If there's no way to define stride, then you'll have to split it up into multiple buffers.

Comment: Damn it... I tried two buffers and still as soon as I call 'setVertexBufferAt(...)' and assign a third attribute (va2) it doesn't render anything. I wonder what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Actually, perhaps this is a rookie mistake, but it was something completely irrelevant to offsets or strides, I'll write my answer in a few seconds...